# Writing a C HTTP Proxy Server -- how to receive and redirect an HTTP response

Tags: http, proxy, network-programming

I'm testing with firefox at the moment. The server receives an HTTP request from firefox as a string, and now I'm uncertain of what to do with it. Do I need to connect to port 8080 and send out the request as a string? Then listen on port 8080 for a response? If so, what will the response come as? I'm not sure what type of content to expect. A string of HTML? Which I then send back to firefox, also as a string?

Also, fyi, from other reading I've gotten the idea that there are lots of different kinds of proxies-- I don't know anything about that yet. My proxy just needs to serve as a middleman between the client and the actual internet, doing nothing else.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the purpose of the proxy. Is it basically just to hide the IP of (or handle a non-public IP on) the browsing machine? And is there some specific reason you can't or don't want to use an off-the-shelf solution like Squid? Also, is performance important? (If so, this is a *big* job.)

Comment: It's a class project. Just needs to filter out some domains provided via command line arguments. I'm not looking for any code, just a general path to follow. And no, definitely no performance. This is a small thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is homework, look at his last question

Comment: @Aerovistae: you should really exchange one of the tags with homework

Comment: Alright, although I have a question: what good is that tag? It's not like it's going to attract people specializing in homework, right? it doesn't actually help.

Comment: Aero, If you ask homework questions without that tag, people will consider you to be dishonest, and be unwilling to help.

Comment: The official ruling is that homework is deprecated (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). This question can stand on its own without the homework tag and therefore it is removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules for proxying HTTP are actually quite complex. But you can probably get away with ignoring most of them, especially if you don't care about performance.

First, you'll have to listen on some port. You'll need to parse the query you receive. It will consist of some number of lines, each followed by a CRLF pair. You'll know the end of the query headers by two CRLF pairs. There can be a query body (if this is a POST) and you don't want to have to parse that because it's complicated. So here's how you'll fake it:

1. Check the query for any `Connection` headers. If you get any, remove them.
2. Make a connection to the server on the other end.
3. After you send the request and the request headers, but before the second CRLF that marks the end of the request headers, add a `Connection: close` header. Then send the second CRLF.
4. Now proxy in *both* directions. You can use an additional process or additional thread if you're too lazy to use `select` or `poll`. Make sure to correctly proxy a half-closed connection. (The browser may shut down sending when it finishes its query -- it's still listening for the reply.)
5. The browser should not attempt to re-use the connection. If HTTP/1.0, it will need specific permission to do that, which it will not get. If HTTP/1.1, the server should accept its `Connection: close` request and respond with a `Connection: close` header of its own.

Note that HTTPS is actually simpler. You'll have to parse `CONNECT` requests if you need to support that too. But then you just connection to the other side, report success or failure, and go into bidirectional proxy mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the request to get to the URL that the client wants. That URL holds the piece of information you need: the name of the server to connect to. The client is connecting to your proxy, but actually wants `http://example.com`.  You have to make a connection to `example.com`. After that, you can be a totally transparent TCP proxy. Handle the bidirectional data transfer properly, as well as TCP half-close. Forward the request that you intercepted and parsed.

You are right in that there are different kinds of proxies, because proxies are not always transparent. A proxy can provide extra authentication and encryption. Or it can filter the HTML: for instance remove or shrink images for faster surfing on low-bandwidth networks. Or it can provide caching to an entire LAN, so people don't download the same file multiple times.

The first thing you should do is write completely generic proxy for TCP: a port forwarder. This is a program which is configured with an IP and port number to connect to. It listens for a client connection, connects to the configured IP and port destination, and then passes the data between that and the client.

If you can't write this, you will have trouble making a HTTP proxy, which is similar, but gets its configuration from the client request (more complicated).